# Unable to locate awscam package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-deeplens

I did factory reset the Amazon DeepLens device.

While installing the `awscam` module it says like unable to locate the package. Can anyone help me how to install complete OS in Amazon DeepLens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My recollection is that it takes a bit of playing around to get `awscam` working. I used a virtual environment and had to put the `.so` file in the `library` directory. (But I did not do a factory reset.) This might help: [AWS Developer Forums: awscam module, open source and Python 3 ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=857536)

Comment: Might also be useful: [aws-deeplens-user-guide/troubleshooting-device-registration.md at master · awsdocs/aws-deeplens-user-guide](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-deeplens-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/troubleshooting-device-registration.md)